# keep elements in list of lists which appear at least twice

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I start with

```py
import polars as pl
ser = pl.Series([[1,2,1,4], [3, 3, 3, 4], [1,2,3,4]])
```

How can I filter each list so it only has elements which appear at least twice?

Expected output:

```py
shape: (3,)
Series: '' [list[i64]]
[
        [1, 1]
        [3, 3, 3]
        []
]
```

Is there a way to do this in polars, without using `apply`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the previous solution was:

```
ser.list.eval(
    pl.element().filter(pl.element().count().over(pl.element()) > 1)
)
```

However, `.over()` is no longer valid inside `.eval()` https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8721

It does appear to be possible with `.value_counts()` but there must be a simpler way:

```
ser.list.eval(
   pl.element().filter(
      pl.element().is_in(
         pl.element().value_counts(sort=True).struct[""].filter(
            pl.element().value_counts(sort=True).struct["counts"] > 1
         )
      )
   )
)
```

```
shape: (3,)
Series: '' [list[i64]]
[
    [1, 1]
    [3, 3, 3]
    []
]
```

Comment: D'oh, I was too focused on the counting part. Please see/accept @Mondo30003's answer.

Comment: `>1` was just an example, I think your answer generalises better

Answer (score 1):

I think filtering elements with `is_duplicated` does the trick

```
ser.list.eval(
    pl.element().filter(pl.element().is_duplicated())
)

    Series: '' [list[i64]]
[
    [1, 1]
    [3, 3, 3]
    []
]
```

Comment: OK, it does here because I've got `>1`, but it wouldn't generalise to `>2`. thanks anyway for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by casting series to list and using `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
import polars as pl

nested_lists = ser.to_list()

counts = [Counter(lst) for lst in nested_lists]

filtered_lists = [[x for x in lst if counts[i][x] >= 2] for i, lst in enumerate(nested_lists)]

filtered_ser = pl.Series(filtered_lists)

print("Series:", filtered_ser)
```

Answer (score 0):

If changing data type is acceptable then you can do use

```py
 list(map(lambda x:[i for i in x if x.count(i)>=2], ser.to_list()))
```

Comment: I'm afraid not - I've amended the question to make it clear this needs doing in polars (and without `apply`)